# SELECT DATE_FORMAT with Zend DB-Table

Tags: zend-framework, date, select, format

is it possible to get the Timestamp right formated with the Zend_Db_Select adapter like "SELECT DATE_FORMAT...." ?

Comment: I don't think there is an inbuilt function for that. You have to use the DB specific function through the Zend_DB_Expr class.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$database->select ()->from ('table', array (new Zend_Db_Expr ('DATE_FORMAT("...")')));
```

form.